# Доступа к самому Mikrotik извне по ssh нет

Tags: ssh, mikrotik

Внутри сети подключаюсь к роутеру всё в порядке.

```
user@himik:~$ ssh -p 12345 -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_mikro abcdef@192.168.0.1
[abcdef@MikroG] >
```

А из дома тишина :

```
alex@linux-5y4f:~> ssh -p 12345 -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_mikro abcdef@195.18.18.18
```

Роутер висит на выделенном адресе, ssh подключения на сервер внутри сети работает, а на сам роутер нет. Что-то нужно разрешить. Не знаю как.

/ip firewall nat

```
add action=src-nat chain=srcnat comment=Internet out-interface=bridge1WAN \
 to-addresses=195.18.18.18
add action=dst-nat chain=dstnat comment=\
 "80=HTML,443=HTMLS,58259=SSH trans to 1.2" dst-port=80,443,58259 \
 in-interface=bridge1WAN protocol=tcp to-addresses=192.168.1.2
add action=src-nat chain=srcnat comment="HTMLS Server answer to 1.1" \
 dst-address=192.168.1.2 dst-port=80,443,58259 protocol=tcp src-address=\
 !192.168.0.0/16 to-addresses=192.168.1.1
add action=dst-nat chain=dstnat comment="MySql to server second net" \
 dst-port=23801 in-interface=bridge1WAN protocol=tcp to-addresses=\
 192.168.1.2 to-ports=3306
add action=src-nat chain=srcnat dst-address=192.168.1.2 dst-port=3306 \
 protocol=tcp to-addresses=192.168.1.1
add action=dst-nat chain=dstnat comment=\
 "HTTPS From Local Net to Public IP -> masque to 1.2" dst-address=\
 195.18.18.18 dst-port=80,443 protocol=tcp src-address=192.168.0.0/16 \
 to-addresses=192.168.1.2
add action=src-nat chain=srcnat dst-address=192.168.1.2 dst-port=80,443 \
 protocol=tcp src-address=192.168.0.0/16 to-addresses=192.168.1.1
add action=dst-nat chain=dstnat comment="alex ssh" dst-port=14396 \
 in-interface=bridge1WAN protocol=tcp to-addresses=192.168.0.10
add action=masquerade chain=srcnat dst-address=192.168.1.0/24 src-address=\
 192.168.0.0/24
add action=masquerade chain=srcnat dst-address=192.168.0.0/24 src-address=\
 192.168.1.0/24
add action=dst-nat chain=dstnat comment="silent wifi ssh" dst-port=51491 \
 in-interface=bridge1WAN protocol=tcp to-addresses=192.168.0.8
add action=dst-nat chain=dstnat comment="tan wifi ssh" dst-port=11357 \
 in-interface=bridge1WAN protocol=tcp to-addresses=192.168.0.9
add action=dst-nat chain=dstnat comment="Mikrotik from internet outside" \
 dst-port=12345 in-interface=bridge1WAN protocol=tcp to-addresses=192.168.1.1
```

/ip firewall filter

```
add action=accept chain=input comment="Good connections" connection-state=established,related
add action=drop chain=input comment="Kill bad" connection-state=invalid
add action=accept chain=input comment="Ping me" protocol=icmp
add action=drop chain=input comment="Kill all inputs" in-interface-list=!LAN log=yes
add action=accept chain=forward comment="Good transit" \
  connection-state=established,related,untracked
add action=drop chain=forward comment="Bad transit" connection-state=invalid
add action=drop chain=forward comment="drop all from WAN to LAN" \
  connection-nat-state=!dstnat connection-state=new in-interface=bridge1WAN
add action=accept chain=forward comment="to MySQL pass from WAN" \
  dst-port=3306 in-interface=bridge1WAN protocol=tcp
add action=accept chain=forward ipsec-policy=in,ipsec
add action=accept chain=forward ipsec-policy=out,ipsec
add action=fasttrack-connection chain=forward connection-state=established,related
```

/ip service

```
set www address=192.168.0.0/16,fe80::/64 port=18671
set ssh port=12345
set www-ssl address=192.168.0.0/16,fe80::/64 certificate=Webfig 
disabled=no port=16190
```

Comment: У микротиков, насколько я знаю, параноидальная настройка sucrity насчет внешних подключений. Наверняка там можно как то поставить галочки в интерфейсе, но, может, обойти проблему, запустив на машине в локальной сети удаленный доступ, и уже через неё получая доступ к роутеру? Такой бэкдор своими руками...

Comment: Я через сервер внутри сети и стучу пока. Хотелось прямую связь с микротиком. @S.H.

Comment: Покажите `/ip firewall filter export` и `/ip service export`

Comment: фильтры вроде ковырял. может быть их все пока отлючить? @Alexey Ten

Comment: ну так ведь фильтр убивает все новые входящие соединения на роутер если они не из локальной сети.

Comment: Это вы про "Kill all inputs" ? Открыть только для нужного порта ? @dash1121

Comment: Да. Ваш Kill all inputs запрещает весь входящий трафик. Надо добавить до него исключение для tcp/12345

Comment: Поставил в `ip firewall filter` разрешение, вроде уже пашет. Надо ещё поковыряться, нужен-ли мне в **nat** перенаправление **dst-nat** на 192.168.1.1. Не могу понять, почему порты 80/443 пропускаются, а 12345 нет. @Alexey Ten

Comment: Для ssh dst-nat не нужен. 80/443 пропускается именно потому что для них настроен dst-nat на **другой** хост и они обрабатываются в цепочке forward, а ssh на сам микротик обрабатывается в цепочке input

Comment: Напишите как ответ, теперь дошло. @Alexey Ten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По комментариям [Alexey Ten](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/190728/alexey-ten) дошло, что даже если указывать перенаправление `/ip firewall nat` с `chain=dstnat` по IP адресу, если этот адрес на сам микротик, то обработка `/ip firewall input` будет как `chain=input`, а не как `chain=forward`.

По-этому добавляю

```
chain=input action=accept protocol=tcp dst-port=12345
```

вместо

```
chain=forward ...
```